# The number of triangles and lines

Tags: combinatorics

Consider 8 vertices of a regular octagon and its centre. If T denotes the number of triangles and S denotes the number of straight lines that can be formed with these 9 points then T - S  has the value 
a) 44  b) 48  c) 52  d) 56

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: T = 9C3 -4=80 , S = 9C2 - 8 = 28 , so T - S  = 80 - 28 = 52

Answer (score 3):

The solution you have given as a comment is correct: Any three of the nine given points determine a "triangle". Four of these triangles are degenerate, and should not be counted. Any two vertices of the octagon determine a line. In this way the possible lines through the center of the octagon  are already counted. It follows that
$$T-S={9\choose 3}-4+{8\choose 2}=52\ .$$

Comment: Can you tell how did you find the number of degenerate triangles?